# Emacs Lisp: Disable extension of surrounding text properties to new text

Tags: text, emacs, fonts

In Emacs by default, if some text has a property (the color green, for instance) and a user types new text into the middle of it, that new text will have the same property. I would like to disable that; I want new text to be black, regardless of where it is inserted. Is it possible?

(My motivation reason is that in [Emacs brain-mode](https://github.com/synchrony/brain-mode), which allows a user to manipulate a Neo4j graph using [Semantic Synchrony](https://github.com/synchrony/smsn), this would make it easy to see which changes have not yet been pushed to the graph.)

Comment: See the Elisp manual, node [Sticky Properties](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sticky-Properties.html).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as Drew says, you can mark the properties of interest as non-sticky on both sides.  Or you can use something like

```
(add-hook 'after-change-functions
          (lambda (beg end _len)
            (put-text-property beg end '<theprop> nil))
          nil t)
```